# installing dependecies error, no luck with --force or --legacy-peer-deps

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui, dependencies, package.json

I am starting a new p[roject/following with react and while I am trying to install the dependencies mentioned in the video i am following I have ran into this error, that I dont know how to resolve myself.

the dependencies and error messages are as such:

```
npm install @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons @material-ui/lab @react-google-maps/api axios google-dash-map-react
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: travel_app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project   
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\pogibro\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pogibro\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-15T11_16_51_369Z-debug-0.log
```

Here is whats in my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "travel_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried finding similar errors, but with no luck. Tried --froce and --legacy-peer-deps but didnt work!

Answer (score 0):

[@material-ui/core@4.12.4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core) is incompatible with `React 18.x` and it has been deprecated. Please use [MUI v5](https://mui.com/)

Let's check the peer dependencies of MUI v4:

```
$ npm view @material-ui/core@4.12.4 peerDependencies
{
  '@types/react': '^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0',
  react: '^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0',
  'react-dom': '^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0'
}
```

As you can see, MUI v4 work with `React ^16.8.0` or `React ^17.0.0`. But in your project, the React version is `^18.2.0` which is incompatible.

Related issue:

- https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33216
- [[core] Update peer deps to support React 18](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/pull/32063)

The MUI v5.6.0 start to support React 18, the latest version is `5.13.6`(until 2023.7.4). So you can install the latest version.